# VBA - UserForm Button (Macro) to Continue running the sub

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sub called as `sub1()` which activates the userform1 through the command `userform1.show()`

This userform1 has a button called as continue. On clicking that button continue - A Macro called as `Private Sub continuebutton()` gets activated.

I want to program in such a way that it redirects to the line after `userform1.show()` in `sub1()`.

Is it something that can be done?

Comment: Give more code.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your thoughts.

Comment: You could just hide the form in the button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, what you want is possible, if you do it like this:

In the UserForm:

```
Private Sub btnContinue_Click()
    flag = True
    Debug.Print "I continue ..."
    sub1
End Sub
```

In a module:

```
Public flag As Boolean

Public Sub sub1()

    If flag Then
        Debug.Print "sub 1 continues here..."
    Else
        flag = False
        UserForm1.Show
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

It will work exactly as intended, **BUT** it is not a good practice to work this way. (Some people may throw stones at you for using public variables at all in VBA.) Here are two articles, that give better ideas:

- https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/

*Disclaimer - this one is mine:*

- http://www.vitoshacademy.com/vba-the-perfect-userform-in-vba/

Answer (score 1):

On the form properties for userform1, set its "Modal" property to true.

When the form opens, it will have exclusive focus, and the code in sub1 will not continue running until after it closes. This may be the solution you need.

In the code below, the msgbox will only appear once userform1 closes:

```
sub sub1()
    userform1.show()
    msgbox "Now continuing with sub1"
end sub
```

Answer (score 1):

No way as long as you show the form.

If you show the form *modal*, the calling routine continues if (and only if) the form is closed.

If you show the form *non-modal*, the code continues to run directly after the `show` - so it's already done.

So either you have to close the form when the user clicks the "continue..." button to let the calling macro continue or you have to split your code into two routines and call the second on button-click.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your Sub1 as follows:

```
Sub sub1(Optional Continue As Boolean)

   If Continue = True Then
      DoSomeStuff
      Exit Sub
   End If
   userform1.show

End sub
```

And then, you can call your `sub1` using:

```
Private Sub continuebutton()
   Call sub1(True)
End Sub
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to go with the 'Modal Form' solution, you could add a subroutine to your main module, and call it when required. So, in userform1, you have:

```
sub sub1()
    userform1.show()
end sub

public sub sub2()
    msgbox "Now continuing..."
end sub
```

And then in userform1, set some code on its onClose event:

```
Private Sub continuebutton()
    Call sub2()
end sub
```